# Theano: how to disable `-march=native`?

Tags: theano

Via the [Theano FAQ](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/faq.html), Theano automatically adds `-march=native`. This breaks the cached compiled modules when I run it on another older CPU, e.g. with such an error:

```
PROGRAM DEFECTIVE (TERMINATED BY SIGNAL):
Illegal instruction

Creating stack trace (innermost first):
#2  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0) [0x2b0304efc4b0]
#3  /u/bozheniuk/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.4--generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial-x86_64-2.7.12-64/lazylinker_ext/lazylinke
r_ext.so(+0x4d2a) [0x2b030fe44d2a]
#4  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x8a51) [0x2b0304453961]
#5  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x85c) [0x2b030458904c]
...
```

How can I disable that, such that it does not automatically adds `-march=native`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be the way:

In `~/.theanorc`, add e.g. this (for a CPU which is old enough; see [here for a list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html)):

```
[gcc]
cxxflags=-march=core2
```

If you get this warning:

```
WARNING (theano.gof.cmodule): WARNING: your Theano flags `gcc.cxxflags` specify an `-march=X` flags.
         It is better to let Theano/g++ find it automatically, but we don't do it now
```

It probably means that you have Theano 0.8. Theano >=0.9 should not print this warning anymore.